# Size of an empty document in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We are planning to create a chatroom app using flutter and firebase. The currently decided way to store chats is to create a new document for each message, with metadata and message text. But we are unsure what is the size overhead of a new document created in firestore, as there can be millions of messages we don't want just the document overhead to go over few GB's.

We tried official docs and googling but found no results for this query

Comment: If you want to constantly check the size of a document than you can use this [Firebase Extension](https://extensions.dev/extensions/alexmamo/firestore-document-size).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size) tells you everything you need to know:

> The size of a document is the sum of:
>
> - The document name size
> - The sum of the string size of each field name
> - The sum of the size of each field value
> - 32 additional bytes

The first item only you know so far, the size of the document name. This is not optional - all documents must have a name/ID.

The second item is 0, since an empty document has no field names.

The third item is 0, since an empty document has no field values.

The fourth item is constant for all documents.

So, an empty document is 32 bytes plus the size of the document name you provided.

Comment: Thank you so much, and sorry for this oversight from out team.